# NSIS xml read and write with escaped characters

Tags: xml, nsis

I have a C# console app which will have username and password field, when user enters user name, password , the value gets saved into a xml. If the name or password is entered with some special characters **&<>'"** the xml is updated with escaped format like **&**

```
<Password>a331&amp;</Password>
```

when i try to read the name field value using **XML plugin** and update the same value. It is saved as **"a331&"** in xml which produces invalid xml when validate with online XMLValidator.

Please some one help on this, how to update the xml file with the escaped characters from nsis

Comment: There is more than one xlm plug-in, link to the one you are using.

Comment: i m using https://nsis.sourceforge.io/XML_plug-in

Comment: It uses the TinyXML library and might need to be updated to the latest version. Try contacting the author...

Comment: Sure and thanks... Can you suggest some other way to implement my requirement?

Comment: Try a different plug-in